# Bing Maps: TileLayer Event

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

Is there a event that is called when the tile layer is loaded (e.g. OnLoaded)? I have a data source (WMS) that I'm using and have set the map type of the map to Mercator. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt762880.aspx)

The AnimateTileLayer seems to have the event, by adding a listener to OnFrameLoaded (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt772216.aspx)

I couldn't find one for TileLayer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event for this on the TileLayer class and no plan to add one.